# Highlight paragraphs in MS-Word doc based on list of paragraph group numbers to highlight?

Tags: database, excel, ms-word, reporting, highlighting

I have several-page MS-Word document with paragraphs where every few paragraphs has a new paragraph number. See example below. Separately, in MS-Excel or CSV file, I have two columns of information -- paragraph number and whether it should be highlighted or not:

```
Paragraph Number, Highlight?

1, True
2, False
3, True
```

**What's the easiest way to end up with the groups of paragraphs listed as "True" in the control list above highlighted in the Word doc?**

```
All about fruits

Apples

Paragraph group 1

Each person shall eat one apple a day to keep the doctor away.

Note: Apples are a red fruit.

Apples have been growing for a long time. Sometimes they fall off the tree by themselves. Sometimes you have to pick them.

Pears

Paragraph group 2

Pears shall be sliced before being eaten.

Pears are usually green, and better when a little soft.

Note: Pears have a distinctive shape

Tomatoes

Paragraph group 3

Tomatoes shall be washed before being eaten.

Note: Tomatoes really are a fruit, not a vegetable.

Or rather, vegetable is not a scientific term. It is a common term.
```

Answer (score 0):

The below example uses Word VBA to reach into Excel and get the worksheet data, which is then used to define the ranges for highlighting within the document. In order for this code to work, make sure to reference the **Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library**.

[image: Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library]

```
Public Sub HighlightParaGroups()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim r As Integer 'Total rows of data
Dim rngStartPoint As Range
Dim rngEndPoint As Range

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Hard coded path to Excel worksheet
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\SO Data Test.xlsx")
Set xlWS = xlApp.Worksheets(1)

'This is the hard coded amount of rows for the example given.
'If row amount will vary, write a sub to detect range of data
r = 3
ActiveDocument.Select

For x = 1 To r
    Debug.Print xlWS.Cells(x, 2)
    If xlWS.Cells(x, 2) = "True" Then 'test for values to highlight
        Set rngStartPoint = DefineHighlightRange(x, True)
        If x + 1 <= r Then
            x = x + 1
            Set rngEndPoint = DefineHighlightRange(x, False)
            x = x - 1
        Else 'In case last paragraph needs to be highlighted
            ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Select
            Selection.Collapse
            Set rngEndPoint = Selection.Range
        End If
        rngStartPoint.SetRange Start:=rngStartPoint.Start, End:=rngEndPoint.Start
        rngStartPoint.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    End If
Next

xlWB.Close False ' close the workbook without saving
xlApp.Quit ' close the Excel application
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here's the function used to define the ranges:

```
Public Function DefineHighlightRange(x As Integer, DecisionFlag As Boolean) As Range

'DecisionFlag determines if the selection needs to be 
'repositioned for the start point of the range
Selection.Find.Text = "Paragraph group " & x
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.HomeKey
If DecisionFlag = True Then
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
End If
Set DefineHighlightRange = Selection.Range

End Function
```

Hope this helps.